# How to change that django checks other boolean field instead of is_staff for admin panel authentication?

Tags: django, django-admin, custom-authentication

I have custom "AUTH_USER_MODEL" as follows:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_institute_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        app_label = perm.split('.')[0]
        if self.is_institute_admin:
            return app_label == 'Profiler'
        if self.is_superuser:
            return app_label == 'Accountant'

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        if self.is_institute_admin:
            return app_label == 'Profiler'
        if self.is_superuser:
            return app_label == 'Accountant'
```

I want that when user logs in to django admin panel, authentication must check `is_institute_admin` instead of its by default `is_staff`.

I added and registered in `settings.py` a custom authentication file as below:

```
class CustomBackend:

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            print('user value =', user, password)

            password_valid = check_password(password=password, encoded=user.password)
            if password_valid:
                if user.is_superuser or user.is_institute_admin:
                    print('returning user')
                    return user
                return None
            else:
                print('password not matched')
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

As for debugging, I added some print statements and it prints till `print('returning user')` but authentication fails.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't to do with the auth backend, but with the user model. The model always needs an `is_staff` attribute, but that could conceivably be a property that returns the value of your other field:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_institute_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_institute_admin
```

Although I must say, it would be easier to keep the field as `is_staff` and just change the label on the relevant forms.